# javascript onclick leave behind

Tags: javascript, onclick

Currently, I am open a new tab on click my body but its changed the focus to the child window. But I want to do it by leaving behind the window so that popup will not block and I can get focus on my current window.

Following code is currently working

```
 /**
* For writing cookie
* @param name {String} name of the cookie
* @param value {*} value of the cookie
* @param days {Number} number of days
*/
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
var expires = "";
if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
  expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

/**
* Get cookie by a name
* @param name {String}
* @returns {*}
*/
function getCookie(name) {
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
 }
return null;
}

/**
* Check for already redirected or not. If not then redirect to targeted site.
*/
function redirectToTarget() {
 var isAlreadyRedirected = getCookie('redirect');
 if (null === isAlreadyRedirected) {
  setCookie('redirect', 1, 30); // write for 1 month
  window.open('https://www.google.com');
 }
}
```

And call js function from body onclick like the following way

```
<body onclick="redirectToTarget()">
```

Any type of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your site in the new tab and reload the targeted URL in the current tab. The following JS snippet can help you.

```
function redirectToTarget() {
    var isAlreadyRedirected = getCookie('redirect');
    if (null === isAlreadyRedirected) {
        setCookie('redirect', 1, 30); // write for 1 month

        var current_loc = window.location.href;
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
        window.open(current_loc);
    }
}
```